# Magento display empty parts in Category page when click on toolbar

Tags: magento-1.8, pagination, toolbar

I am currently working on Magento and installed one custom theme [Porto](http://newsmartwave.net/magento/porto/index.php/demo3_en/fashion.html?___SID=U&ajaxcatalog=true&).

When I clicked on any option of toolbar at that time all products load using ajax but display some empty part.

[image]

Here blank place come when click on pagination using Ajax Toolbar.
Any thing wrong ?

Comment: Check browser Consolve any error

Comment: Consolve does not give any types of error.

Comment: Share Your URL?

Comment: What is the problem

Comment: When you go to next page at that time products not display properly. Its give blank space as per attachment of image.

Comment: You mean some product allignment or what

Comment: Some product allignment not proper display

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39723/discussion-between-learning-phase-and-kothari).